# Python (spyder) - name 'debugfile' is not defined

Tags: python, spyder

I'm a beginner at programming and I need to do it for a university course. The programme I'm using is Spyder (downloaded last night) and I have to code in 'python'. I've downloaded the version required, but I can't seem to run a simple code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""

import math

def circleAreaFromDiameter(d):
    """takes a float d and returns the area of a cirlce with diameter d.
    """
    Area = math.pi * d**2/4.0
    return Area

print circleAreaFromDiameter(1)
```

The last line, "print circleAreaFromDiameter(1)" has an exclamation mark at the side of it saying that it's an invalid syntax. I don't understand why, but I don't think that's my problem.

When I press the "run file" or "debug file", it says:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'runfile' is not defined

or

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'debugfile' is not defined

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: It looks like you're using an IDE. Don't forget to explain how you're trying to run your program, as this will help people answer your question. Also, if you want to have an empty function, you can use the `pass` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Clean up your line breaks, and I think it should run fine.  It owrks for me in this form:

```
import math

def circleAreaFromDiameter(d):
    """takes a float d and returns the area of a cirlce with diameter d. """
    area = math.pi * d**2/4.0
    return area

print circleAreaFromDiameter(1)
```

The problem was pasting the Area assignment on the same line with the block quote (triple-quoted string).

Comment: Ahh, thanks for pointing that out. I've also miraculously solved my namefile error by opening it up the next morning and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed a Python 3, the print syntax is now

`print (circleAreaFromDiameter(1))`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Putting the extra brackets has removed the exclamation mark at the side. I've also got the runfile button to work as well. I had to open up a new console. When I opened up spyder for the second time just now, the namefile error went away for some reason.